# how to replace non ascii characters with empty values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

how to replace non ascii character with empty values in postgresql

```
table :Emp
address
Îlt-t-Fce
ÄddÄ« ÄrkÊ¿ay
Ê¿AlÅ«la
```

based on above data i wantoutput like below

```
Address
Ilt-t-Fce
AddAArkEay
EAlAla
```

I tried like below

```
SELECT replace(addres,'%[^a-Z0-9, ]%',' ')
FROM emp
WHERE address like '%[^a-Z0-9, ]%'
or 
select   replace(addres,'^[^[:ascii:]]',' ') from  emp where  address ~ '^[^[:ascii:]]'
```

above two queris are not giving expected result
can you please tell me how to write query to replace for non ascci chareater with empty values in postgresql

Answer (score 3):

In the first query, you're trying to use `LIKE` with a regex, but that's not possible so you're excluding the results you want to replace characters in. See `SIMILAR TO` and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-matching.html for more details.

Moreover, the `replace` function works with strings but doesn't accept regular expressions. You have to use `regexp_replace`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-string.html.

Your solution is:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(address, '[^[:ascii:]]', '', 'g');
FROM emp
WHERE address SIMILAR TO '%[^[:ascii:]]%';
```

The `g` flag means global, so it will replace every occurrence. If you omit it, it will only remove the first occurrence.

Other examples:

To exclude accented characters:

```
select regexp_replace(address, '[À-ÿ]', '', 'g');
```

To exclude non-alphanumeric characters:

```
select regexp_replace(address, '[^[:alnum:]]', '', 'g');
```