# Proc SQL to Postgres UFT8 database: non printable character shown as normal question mark, can't remove

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, sas

I need advice for a problem I'm facing:
I use SAS 9.4 (desktop version) to connect to a Postgres database with the Unicode Postgres ODBC driver.
I'm using a proc sql statement to retrieve the data and create a sas data file.

There is one issue:
One entry has the following value in the database it PgAdmin: "CAR "

But when I look at the SAS data file that proc sql created it looks like this: "CAR ?"
Just a normal question mark.

The compress function with `_FIELD = compress(_FIELD, ,'kw');` doesn't seem to work, as the question mark is just a normal question mark and not a non printable character.

Postgres database has UTF8 as server encoding.
The ODBC connection uses Unicode Postgres drivers.
I tried running SAS with the English (creates a Wlatin1 dataset) and Unicode option (creates a UTF8 dataset) but nothing changes.

I would like to be able to remove this character.

Any tips or suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this kb article](https://support.sas.com/kb/52/685.html) which, while describing a totally different issue, might be helpful in the suggested environment variable?

Comment: And - in the question, your text looks like "CAR [unknown characater box]".  Does it actually look like that in Postgres?  If it does, then SAS is probably transcoding it "properly" from SAS's point of view - SAS uses `?` to indicate unknown character, and then the issue is in however you got the data into Postgres.

Comment: The article says PGCLIENTENCODING is only for Linux/Unix environments. I'm running SAS on Windows 10.

Also,  Python shows the values as "CAR \uf05a".
My problem is: I would like to dynamically filter/replace non-unicode characters but I can't do that if it has been transformed into a standard question mark as I can't differentiate it from a normal question mark in a field.

I also tried if there is a differences between Proc SQL or Passthrough SQL in SAS, but it is not. Both options give me the "CAR ?" result

Comment: Hmm, that's a private use codepoint so it will indeed often be set to unknown-char.  What happens if you set the data set encoding (see [this communities.sas.com question for example](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Latin-9-in-one-database-to-UTF-8-in-another/td-p/612072))?  Particularly, PUT the value with $HEX. to see its underlying.  Also - definitely do this with SAS in UTF8 mode (even better, in DBCS mode).

Comment: Thank you Joe, I appreciate your help, but I'm not sure how I can use information you linked to.

I have this code:
options dlcreatedir;
libname sql_read odbc dsn=OSBCcon schema=database;



PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE work.tableA as
SELECT _FIELD
FROM sql_read.tableA;
WHERE ID=123 and _FIELD2=AB
QUIT;

The one line I get back has already the question mark in there, SAS shows "CAR ?"

I also tried Proc SQL vs Passthrough SQL but that doesn't make a difference either

Comment: Read the comments on the thread - Tom shows how to use dataset options to define the encoding of the dataset.  I'm not sure if it will help or not, but it's the next step I'd take.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is more than 2 1/2 years old, but would you be able to do a direct connection to the Postgres DB, and strip the non-ASCII characters out there before it coming through in SAS? For example, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55824371/9990662) to strip non-ASCII characters, you might be able to do something like this:

```
proc sql;

    CONNECT TO ODBC (dsn=OSBCcon);

    CREATE TABLE work.tableA as 
    SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO ODBC
    (
        SELECT regexp_replace(_FIELD, '[^[:ascii:]]', '', 'g') AS field_ascii
        FROM my_database.tableA 
        WHERE ID=123 and _FIELD2=AB
    );

    DISCONNECT FROM ODBC;

quit;
```