# Postgres SQL to remove only non-ascii characters from a string

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have data in Postgres something as below , there is possibility of having mutiple non-ascii chars in a string

| Name |
| --- |
| Kate SolutionǸǸs |
| Etak Solutions |

We are trying to identify if there are any NON-ASCII char set from the string and remove all of them if there are any(if there no non-ascii then keep the string as is) and expecting output below output

| Name |
| --- |
| Kate Solutions |
| Etak Solutions |

Tried using below SQL but its just removing only one non-ascii char irrespective of the position where it is present

```
select REGEX_REPLACE(name,'[^ -~]', '') as new_name from table
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to replace non ascii characters with empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821833/how-to-replace-non-ascii-characters-with-empty-values) The solution shown there works correctly, see https://dbfiddle.uk/eJ2it5oi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Postgresql documentation:

> If the g flag is given, or if N is specified and is zero, then all matches at or after the start position are replaced. (The g flag is ignored when N is specified.)

So either add a 4th parameter as zero, 0, or add a 6th parameter as 'g'.